# Is it possible to use Ambassador prefix_regex and regex_rewrite at the same route mapping?

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, mapping, envoyproxy, ambassador

I'm trying to use Ambassador `prefix_regex` and `regex_rewrite`. 
I want both this routes prefixes:

```
       /my/route/<something>
      /api/v1/my/route/<something>
```

will be mapped to:
`/my/route/<something>` 
This is what I was trying to use:

```
apiVersion: ambassador/v2
kind: Mapping
prefix_regex: true
prefix: (/api/v1)?/my/route
regex_rewrite:
    pattern: "/api/v1/my/route/(.*)"
    substitution: "/my/route/\\1"
```

Using the `regex_rewrite` with regular `prefix` works as expected 
Using `prefix_regex` with regular `rewrite` works as expected
but together I receive 404 from the envoy.

Any ideas?

I'm using Ambassador 1.7.0 version

Answer (score 1):

Resolved by adding /.* at the end of the prefix.

`prefix:  (/api/v1)?/my/route/.*`

It looks like prefix_regex adds automatically `$` at the end of the prefix, which means we need to specify the full path of the mapping and not just the prefix.